# Qt QSerialPort buffering

Tags: c++, qt

I am reading information from a serial port. How do I wait for a newline to come in, and then deal with the data? That is, how do I make sure I'm chunking a whole line at a time.

This code does not work:

```
void MainWindow::readData()
{
    QByteArray data = serial->readAll(); //reads in one character at a time (or maybe more)
    console->putData(data); 
    charBuffer.append(data); 
    if (data.contains("\n")) //read into a structure until newline received.
    {
        //call parsedata
        sensorValues->parseData(charBuffer); //send the data to be parsed.
        //empty out the structure
        charBuffer = "";
    }
}
```

Let's say the serial port sends "Sensor1 200\n".
data might contain the following: "Se" then "n", "sor 2" "00\n" and so on.

How do I block calling parseData until I have a line of text?

Additional info:
readData is set up as a slot:

```
    connect(serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));
```

Comment: Is that not (almost) what your code does?  Apart from the fact that if you receive "200\nSensor5" in one readData() call, the "Sensor5" part would be passed to parseData as part of the previous line and would not be included in the start of the next line sent to parseData

Comment: when you say 'this code does not work' what output to you get?

Comment: I get the mixed output above. Solution found though: block on canReadLine();

Answer (score 3):

Have you not tried using the SerialPort readLine() function? after each readline(), you can send the line to some new ByteArray or QString to be parsed up. I also use .trimmed() on the end to remove the '\r' and '\n' characters, so I can do something like so:

```
void MainWindow::readData()
{
    while (serial->canReadLine()){
       QByteArray data = serial->readLine();   //reads in data line by line, separated by \n or \r characters
       parseBytes(data.trimmed()) ;
     }
}

 void MainWindow::parseBytes(const QByteArray &data) <--which needs to be moved to       separate class, but here it's in the MainWindow, obviously improper
 {
       if (data.contains("1b0:"))
       {
            channel1Data.b0_code = data.mid(5);   // which equals "1", 
            //do stuff or feed channel1Data.b0_code to a control 
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a static variable and then store data until you got an **\n**

```
void readData()
{
    // Read data
    static QByteArray byteArray;
    byteArray += pSerialPort->readAll();

    //we want to read all message not only chunks
    if(!QString(byteArray).contains("\n"))
        return;

    //sanitize data
    QString data = QString( byteArray ).remove("\r").remove("\n");
    byteArray.clear();

    // Print data
    qDebug() << "RECV: " << data;

    //Now send data to be parsed
}
```