# UART to Qt software error - why data always split?

Tags: c++, qt, microcontroller, uart

I am tryig to display data I receive via UART on my Qt application.
I send all my data from my microcontroller at once, but my qt application receives it in multiple parts why?

this is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEMJE.jpg
in stead of: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpqin.jpg

So every time I receive data my slot function gets called, hence the "data received". But my data is split in two parts. Why please?

my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)//, mijnAnimatie(new animatie())
{  

    serialPort->setPortName("COM13");
        serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);

       // serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
       // serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
       // serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);


        if (!serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
        {
         qDebug("some error when opening\n");
        }
        connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(updateReceivedData()));

}

void MainWindow::updateReceivedData()
{
    qDebug("received data\n");
    QString m_readData;

    ui->receiveLabel->setText(m_readData);


      QByteArray result = serialPort->readAll();
      QString command(result); //to convert byte array to string
      qDebug()<<result;
      ui->receiveLabel->setText(command);
}
```

Comment: Because it is a stream of data, not packets. It takes time for the bytes to be sent and your receiving machine is so fast that you're likely reading some bytes before the others have even been sent yet. You have do buffering in your code, which means either a delimiter character between messages or send the message size before the message data so you know how big it is.

Comment: Like a static variable in my function, which once it receives a"\n" analyses the data? But this is C++ so I cannot do something like if(result[i]=="\n") {break;}, or whatsoever. What would be a correct way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703605/qt-qserialport-buffering

Comment: You need to use canonical mode to invoke the line discipline, e.g. reading *lines* rather than bytes Follow the link that @DarkFalcon provided.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming connections, like TCP/IP or serial ports, give you *zero* guaranties about how the data is cut up into pieces. If you want packets, you have to implement them yourself on top of a streaming connection.