# Can QSerialPort read more than 512 bytes of data?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I want to use QSerialPort to read data transmitted from a device. The device transmits a frame of 4000 data bytes each time. I try with the following simple code

```
QSerialPort *serialPort;
char receivedData[4000];
int numRead = 0;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /* Initialize serial port*/
    serialPort = new QSerialPort(this);
    QString portName = "COM6";
    qint32 baudRate = 460800;
    serialPort->setPortName(portName);
    serialPort->setBaudRate(baudRate);
    serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serialPort->setReadBufferSize(4000);
    if (!serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qDebug() << "Cannot open comport";
    }
    connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(serialReceived()));
}

void MainWindow::serialReceived()
{
    numRead = serialPort->read(receivedData, 4000);
    serialPort->flush();
}
```

The problem is: it always shows that only 512 data bytes are read. How can I read the whole 4000 bytes data frame? (when I'm using Matlab to read this 4000 bytes frame, it's working fine)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29151336/2257050). You have to create your own buffer where you read the data until some specific size you are expecting is met. You can also use [`QSerialPort::bytesAvailable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#bytesAvailable) method to check how many bytes are available.

Comment: Hi, i use a loop to check `QSerialPort::bytesAvailable` , and it always shows 512 bytes.

Comment: Are you reading the data in between checks?

Comment: y, you're right. Now I think of it, it's not the right way to do. However I don't know where should I put `QSerialPort::bytesAvailable`, cause I don't know the program's waiting until `readReady` is emitted ?

Comment: You can use what Ilya suggested, read all data in your own buffer, and once that buffer is 4000 bytes or more, remove the first 4000 bytes from your buffer and do something with that data. The other option that I think will work is, if you take advantage of `QSerialPorts`'s internal buffer. When `readyRead` is emitted, check for `bytesAvailable`. If it is less than 4000, do nothing, if it is 4000 or more, read 4000 bytes until there are less than 4000 bytes available.

Comment: Yes, @llya method works for me. I think your suggestion will also work and i'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit, but you don't necessarily receive all data in single chunk.
You have to keep listening until you have the number of bytes you're waiting for (or a timeout).

```
void MainWindow::serialReceived()
{
    receivedData.append(serialPort->readAll());
    if(receivedData.size() >= 4000) {
       // we're full
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You generally have to read out the data in a loop (to ensure you get it all), here is a snippet of example code this is equivalent to your serialReceived() function, except it emits the data using `emit rxDataReady(newData);` to whoever is listening...

```
void QSerialPortReader::handleReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray newData;

    // Get the data
    while (mp_serialPort->bytesAvailable())
    {
        newData.append(mp_serialPort->readAll());
    }
    emit rxDataReady(newData);
}
```

**edit**

Although I don't do any max size checking... but that is trivial to add if you need it (i.e. just use read(..., spaceAvail) instead of readAll and then decrement spaceAvail...

Comment: Hi, I tried the following code, but it only resulted in 60bytes being read. I don't understand why? <br/>
`void MainWindow::serialReceived() <br/>
{ <br/>
    while (serialPort->bytesAvailable()) <br/>
    { <br/>
        readData.append(serialPort->readAll()); <br/>
    } <br/>
}` <br/>

Comment: Does bytes available show more then 60 bytes? (maybe add a debug line). Also is readReady getting called more then once? One other thing to check, not 100% sure if it is an issue, but it looks like you are running all this in the same thread. It might be safer to use `Qt::QueuedConnection` in your connect() function (its the optional 5th parameter). In your code I don't know what will happen if a second readReady comes in before the first is finished.