# QSerialPort: data is broken into two packets

Tags: qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I'm using QSerialPort class to read data from a hardware module over network using a `Network<->Serial` converter ([Moxa NPort](http://www.moxa.com/product/NPort_5110.htm)). The device sends correct data, but receiver fails to read the whole data packet at once. For example client sends:

```
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0xa
```

and receiver gets

```
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06
```

at first try and

```
0x07 0x08 0x09 0xa
```

On second read attempt.

The port is opened like this:

```
m_port.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
m_port.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
m_port.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
m_port.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
m_port.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
m_port.open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);
m_port.setBreakEnabled(false);
```

And this is how program reads. (Following function is being executed by a timer of 500ms interval, implementing a simple polling protocol)

```
qint64 written_data_size = this->m_port.write(m_openGate);
if(written_data_size == -1){
    emit message("Unable to write to serial port.");
    return;
}
m_port.flush();
bool bytes_written = this->m_port.waitForBytesWritten(100);
if(!bytes_written){
    emit message("No data has been written to serial port.");
    return;
}
// Read status
this->m_port.waitForReadyRead(100);
QByteArray data = this->m_port.readAll(); // ===> Not all packet is read
```

Comment: This is how serial communication works. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592248/can-qserialport-read-more-than-512-bytes-of-data).

Comment: Well, you can't expect all data to arrive at once regardless of the size. That's why when you initiate a transfer, the first thing you transmit is the total packet size, so you receive until you get that many bytes or something went wrong.

Comment: Ah.... Okay I'll handle size myself.